# link google drive pictures to a excel file

Tags: excel, cloud, google-drive-api

I would have liked to do the following: 
create an excel file where every row has a correspondig figure saved somewhere.
For my own purposes (when figures are saved on my file) I use the

```
=hyperlink(pathway/name figure)
```

formula. By standarization of the filename I can easily link all figures to their ID (for example last part of the name is the ID and set in hyperlink the name of the file as the name of that specific cell)

Now I want to share my excel file and my figures to some collaborators
I used google drive for this purpose and made this available for sharing by providing the link.

Now I want to use the hyperlink in the same fashion as previously on my desktop. So as pathway is the link that is provided

There seems however no logic in how files are named
E.g if i look at a file urlI get a very random combination of numbers and letters
E.g the original (structurized) naming is still used in drive as a titlebut is not seen in my url.

My question:
- is the random combination of numbers and letters for all the urls not that random and can i structerize them back 
- can I use the titles in my hyperlink file (don't see how since they don't provide a path)
- is there an alternative cloud system where url naming of a file is related with the title given to a file.

Thanks in advance

Niels